# Space button stopped working with New Unity Input system after implementing new EventSystem

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, event-handling, game-physics

Everything was working perfectly until I started getting random errors for not having the new EventSystem implemented. Now that I've converted it, only the movement works and the spacebar input doesn't work at all.. Can anyone explain why this happened? the "PlayerControls.PlayerControls.Dash.triggered" is the spacebar input.

```
private void Update()
{
    PlayerVelocity = PlayerControls.PlayerControls.movement.ReadValue<Vector2>();
    PlayerVelocity = new Vector3(PlayerVelocity.x, PlayerVelocity.y).normalized;

    if (PlayerControls.PlayerControls.Dash.triggered)
    {
        Dashing = true;
    }
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    rb.velocity = PlayerVelocity * moveSpeed;
    if(Dashing == true)
    {
        float dashAmount = 20f;
        rb.AddForce(rb.velocity * dashAmount, 
        ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        Dashing = false;
    }
}
```